# Outputting Plain Text Using Mustache and Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mustache

I'm using Mustache as a very basic templating engine for my users to create configuration files. I need these formatted as plain text not html.

Currently I have things working fine in my html templates but I can't get it to render as plain text.

I have the following in my html template:

```
 <div id="network" data-json-url="<%= @nas %>">
 <div id="sampleArea2"></div>
 <script id="network_details" type="text/template">
 <%= simple_format(@location.body) %>
 </script>
```

Where @location.body is a user editable text area:

```
 option foo {{ location_sausage }}
 option bar '{{ location_sheep }}'
```

This outputs something like this:

```
 option foo barbara
 option bar 'margo'
```

Is there a simple way to convert this to plain text - previously, before mustache, I just used in my controller:

```
 format.text
```

-- UPDATE --

Previously using erb, I did something like this to render the field in the view as text:

```
 <%= (ERB.new(@config.body).result(binding)).html_safe %>
```

I've tried replacing this with:

```
 <%= Mustache.render(@config.body).html_safe %>
```

But there's no data fetched in the request.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: 1. What exacly library do you use for `Rails` integration?

Comment: 2. Why just not use erb for text templating? For example `index.text.erb`

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/defunkt/mustache And the reason why I'm not using erb is that I didn't want the end user entering <%= @location.something %> Do you think it would be better to go back to pure erb?

Comment: ERB is definitely fastest, but for your case of using `Mustache` as some sort of user-formatting I would keep it with caution as user input should be always processed with care.

Comment: Thanks. Fortunately it's just for admins right now but has already caused issues. Sticking with Mustache and am going to control which vars can be used (somehow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was correct using:

```
 <%= Mustache.render(@config.body).html_safe %>
```

Found I needed to define my variables better:

```
 <%= Mustache.to_html(@config.body, @location).html_safe %>
```

Hope that's helpful to someone out there